# Using instance variable to indicate the view is Edit or Show

Tags: ios, swift

In [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift): Implement Edit and Delete Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1)
, The offical tutorial tell me should use presentingViewController and navigationController to indicate the specified view is Edit or Show, Like following code:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

The adding view is presented by modal, the editing view is presented by embed navigation controller, But I think this approach is not good to understand and easy maintain, How about introduce a `isEditOrShow` instance varible in the view to indicate the state? like following:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.

    if isEditingOrShow = .edit{
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else isEditingOrShow = .show{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial explains that, there are two ways in which you can dismiss view controllers.

For example, when you present a view controller as modal, you can use the below code to dismiss it.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, if you are using a push presentation (Navigation controller), then you should use the below code to dismiss it.

```
owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

> How about introduce a bool isEditOrShow instance varible in the view to indicate the state?

From what I understand, you won't be needing isEditOrShow variable. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: Assume you add a isEditOrShow variable to indicate state. How do you think you will dismiss the views?

Comment: i think isEditOrShow is not a good variable name, what its mean if isEditOrShow == true?